# Add included PHP function to a class?

Tags: php

I have many different PHP-files. Because it is a Wordpress theme I need to include all my functions into a class to avoid collisions.

What I want is having the theme name as a "prefix" (first part of the class name). **Is it possible to use the same class for all functions even if they are in different PHP files?**

**This is how it might look:**

```
myfunctions.php
myfunctions_extra.php
```

"myfunctions.php" includes a function `test` that is added to `class my_class`.

"myfunctions_extra.php" includes a function `test2` that should be added to `class my_class` as well.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: Why don't you use a namespace? Or have one class have methods that are just aliases for the functions in other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. Not in PHP 5.3. The next version will include traits, which make it possible, but in PHP 5.3: NO. Look for a different approach ;)

Maybe you can use namespaces, but I don't know how Wordpress copes with them.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I would change that to say inheritance. That's what it is, after all.

Comment: In hindsight that does make more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Have one main class that has methods bound to the functions from different classes. So, for example, the method `create_sidebar()` in `MyClass` calls the `create_sidebar()` function from whatever file it originates in.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, PHP does not support the notion of partial classes. You're unable to solve your problem this way.

Do you really need a class for this? If you're running on PHP 5.3 you could define a namespace for your files, i don't now how Wordpress plays with them though.

Another option is to "fake" a namespace by adding a prefix to all your methods, and just keep a global variable if you need to keep some sort of state, like this:

```
$myns_settings = array(..);

// file1.php
function myns_firstfunc()
{
    global $myns_settings;
    // You can access myns_settings here
}



// file2.php
function myns_secondfunc()
{
    global $myns_settings;
    // You can access myns_settings here as well
}
```